# Падеж существительного, стоящего после глагола "удовлетворить"

Tags: морфология

Как правильно: "удовлетворяет требования ..." или "удовлетворяет требованиям ..."?
Более логичен, по-моему, первый вариант.
Прошу Вас ответить.

Answer (score 2):

После глагола *удовлетворять* (сов. вид - *удовлетворить*) можно использовать винительный падеж: *удовлетворять аппетит, удовлетворять запрос*. Дательный падеж употребляется только с формой 3-го лица данного глагола в значении 'соответствовать чему-либо': *удовлетворять требованиям, условиям*. Последний вариант более употребителен в официально-деловом стиле. К сожалению, без контекста трудно сказать, какой вариант подходит именно вам.

Answer (score 2):

Если речь идёт о технической документации или переписке на технические темы - а именно там обычно встречается подобное сочетание, то почти наверняка **удовлетворить требованиям**. Вариант *удовлетворить требования* тут выглядит диковато.
С винительным же вернее всего будут не требования, а потребности.
**Удовлетворить требования** - это разве что в рекламации, претензии, судебном иске...

Как верно замечено, у этих двух вариантов разный смысл. 
И если с винительным падежом значение будет "выполнить", сделать довольным или погасить желание (как аппетит), то с дательным - "соответствовать", "подходить". Думаю понятно, какой смысл вернее всего имеется в виду в техническом тексте.

Вот чего я не пойму, так это безапелляционное в большинстве словарей заявление о невозможности использования дательного падежа с 1-м и 2-м лицом. (Кузнецов, например).
Разве фраза "Вы не удовлетвореяте нашим требованиям" (при собеседовании, например) неверна?

Answer (score 0):

Удовлетворить - кого-что? - требования. Таким образом, Вы совершенно правы.